# Regex between > and < in R with stringr

Tags: regex, r

How can i capture the string between > and < in R.

```
 d<-"\"id/56771\" target=\"_self\">Children- and adolescents</a></li>\n\t\t\t<li><"
```

//M

`str_extract(d,">+(.*?)+<")` gives me

```
>Children- and adolescents</a></li>\n\t\t\t<li><
```

I guess a new string command could do the trick, but I thought there would be something more direct...

Comment: it seems like you are trying to parse contents of a webpage. while using `regex` works for simple cases, it might be better to use a parser like the `XML` package to extract contents. if you can post the exact page u are trying to extract info from, some of us can help.

Comment: Ramnath: Web pages are rarely valid and well-formed XML.

Comment: Didn't understand your code. What r is?

Comment: @Saeed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=faq

Comment: @Misha, are you looking for `>Children- and adolescents<` or `>Children- and adolescents</a></li>\n\t\t\t<li><`?

Comment: @Joey. the XML package can parse HTML too. It has worked very well for me in most situations. Of course it depends on how malformed the page is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str_extract`, but `str_match` may be better suited:

```
str_extract(d, ">.*?<")
[1] ">Children- and adolescents<"
```

The trick here is the `?` modifier that tells the regex to be not greedy.  Regex matching is greedy by default, which means that it will match the longest string with your pattern.

This still leaves you with a bit of work to do, i.e. remove the first and last character.  One can do this with vector subsetting, or it might be slightly easier to use `str_match` instead.  This returns all of the pattern matches as an array:

```
str_match(d, ">(.*?)<")
     [,1]                          [,2]                       
[1,] ">Children- and adolescents<" "Children- and adolescents"
```

(The two matches are 1. The entire string, and 2. The pattern inside the brackets.)

This means it's a simple matter of returning the second element:

```
str_match(d, ">(.*?)<")[2]
[1] "Children- and adolescents"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `>([^<]+)<`, probably.

The first match then contains the string you're looking for. It will match multiple times here, though.

**Edit:** Oops, forgot to negate the character class

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you can extract the three components using `gsub` and back-references.

```
> gsub("(^.*?>)(.*?)(<.*$)","\\1",d)
[1] "\"id/56771\" target=\"_self\">"
> gsub("(^.*?>)(.*?)(<.*$)","\\2",d)
[1] "Children- and adolescents"
> gsub("(^.*?>)(.*?)(<.*$)","\\3",d)
[1] "</a></li>\n\t\t\t<li><"
```